# Get URL parameter with Knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

Suppose I have a URL like this:

http://www.example.com/apples?myParam=123&myOtherParam=456

How do I use Knockout JS to retrieve the values of myParam and myOtherParam ?

Comment: is this url from the brower's address bar, inside of a textbox, or stored in a variable?  In any case, as long as you can get to it, you can use the string.split function to parse the data.

Comment: it's a URL from address bar

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse the location. [window.location gives you the current document's location]

```
var paramsString = window.location.split("?")[1];
var paramValues = paramsString.split("&");
var params = new Array();
for(var param in paramValues){
    var paramValue = param.split("=");
    params[paramValue[0]] = paramValue[1];
}
```

to use the params:

```
var myParam = params.myParam; //or
var myOtherParam = params['myOtherParam'];
```

Comment: There are routing libraries out there that can help you, for example SammyJS

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look to this post which shows a nice, simple and small fuction:

```
function $_GET(param) {
var vars = {};
window.location.href.replace( location.hash, '' ).replace( 
    /[?&]+([^=&]+)=?([^&]*)?/gi, // regexp
    function( m, key, value ) { // callback
        vars[key] = value !== undefined ? value : '';
    }
);

if ( param ) {
    return vars[param] ? vars[param] : null;    
}
return vars;}
```

then you can get the variable in a similar way to PHP:

```
name = $_GET('name')
```

Here is the full article: [read URL params with Javascript](https://www.creativejuiz.fr/blog/en/javascript-en/read-url-get-parameters-with-javascript)